# join in oracle using in clause for a list

Tags: oracle

I am having 2 tables, 1 is `transaction`, other is `trackingNumber`

Transaction have `trackingNumberList` which contains the values like `123, 235, 55`.  Here  `123` is the `id` of `trackingNumber`, same  for other 2 values.

I wanna join transaction with trackingNumber but I haven't found any solution to join list.

I tried `INSTR` as well but it is not giving the correct data.

```
select tn.*, t.id
from  transaction t
left join TrackingNumber tn on INSTR(t.trackingnumberlist, tn.id)  > 0
where t.id = 2439845;
```

I am using ORACLE db.

Comment: Don't put comma-separated lists in columns in the first place.

Comment: @Barmar No,  I already tried INSTR but that is giving me some unwanted records as well

Comment: The accepted answer there is wrong, see the other answers.

Comment: The comment below that answer explains why it returns unwanted records. And I know you already tried `INSTR()`, it's in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't split the string; just wrap the list and the id in the delimiter you are using and do a sub-string match using `LIKE`:

```sql
select tn.*, t.id
from   transaction t
       left join TrackingNumber tn
       on (', '||t.trackingnumberlist||', ' LIKE '%, '||tn.id||', %')
where  t.id = 2439845;
```

---

If you want to use `INSTR` to do the same thing:

```sql
select tn.*, t.id
from   transaction t
       left join TrackingNumber tn
       on (INSTR(', '||t.trackingnumberlist||', ', ', '||tn.id||', ') > 0)
where  t.id = 2439845;
```

Comment: getting error: LIKE operator supported only for CHAR, VARCHAR, WCHAR & WVARCHAR fields,  I tried `||cast(tn.id as varchar(50))` but it  also  not works

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma You can use `INSTR` as well, just wrap the values in the delimiters so that you don't match to partial sub-strings of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you split comma-separated values into rows, then you can join such a subquery with another table. Have a look at the following example. Sample data in lines #1 - 11, query you might be interested in begins at line #12.

```
SQL> with
  2  transaction (trackingnumberlist, city) as
  3    (select '123, 235, 55', 'London' from dual union all
  4     select '22'          , 'Paris'  from dual
  5    ),
  6  trackingnumber (id, name) as
  7    (select '123', 'Little' from dual union all
  8     select '235', 'Foot'   from dual union all
  9     select '55' , 'Sharma' from dual union all
 10     select '22' , 'Barmar' from dual
 11    )
 12  select n.id,
 13         n.name,
 14         x.city
 15  from trackingnumber n
 16  join (select trim(regexp_substr(t.trackingnumberlist, '[^,]+', 1, column_value)) id,
 17               t.city
 18        from transaction t cross join
 19          table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 20                              connect by level <= regexp_count(t.trackingnumberlist, ',') + 1
 21                             ) as sys.odcinumberlist ))
 22        ) x
 23    on x.id = n.id
 24  order by n.id, n.name;

ID  NAME   CITY
--- ------ ------
123 Little London
22  Barmar Paris
235 Foot   London
55  Sharma London

SQL>
```